# See the image. It shows the port P3 and pins. Are they both same?

Tags: ports, keil, 8051

[image: a module in 8051 keil debug window]

This is a snap from the debug window in Keil for 8051 Microcontroller. I have done an Embedded C program that would take detect an external interrupt in any of the pins and execute an ISR. 
When I tried to change the value of the pin, it showed up the error "You tried to change the port pin which is configured as output pin"
My doubt is that, what is the difference between P3 and Pins (as shown).

Comment: Your title and text ask different questions. Please clarify what you are asking

Comment: In Keil simulator, you can only change pins which are configured as Input through this Window. To modify pins which are output, you have to write the code.